# DNS lookups failing

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, routing, ubuntu-12.04

Gateway `192.168.122.1` runs dns, and the command `dig @192.168.122.1 www.google.com` returns valid ip addresses, so dns is working and reachable.

The command `tracepath www.google.com` returns `gethostbyname2: Host name lookup failure`.

The command `tracepath 74.125.129.103` (www.google.com) yields valid results, so the default route is set up correctly.

The command `route -n` outputs:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And the applicable portion of `/etc/network/interfaces` reads:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.122.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.122.255
    gateway 192.168.122.1
    dns-servers 192.168.122.1
```

No firewalls are currently running.

I would think, given these settings, that `tracepath www.google.com` would contact `192.168.122.1` for dns information, which is verified to be working and reachable.

What should I do next to find out why the tracepath command returns `gethostbyname2: Host name lookup failure`?

---

**Edit** (more info)

`/etc/resolv.conf` is empty. Ubuntu 12.04 uses a new subsystem, `resolvconf`, that autogenerates resolv.conf data in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*`.

**`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original` contains:**

```
nameserver 192.168.122.1
```

All other `resolv.conf.d` files (`head` and `base`)are empty.

**`/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains:**

```
    passwd:         compat
    group:          compat
    shadow:         compat

    hosts:          files dns
    networks:       files

    protocols:      db files
    services:       db files
    ethers:         db files
    rpc:            db files

    netgroup:       nis
```

**`/etc/hosts` contains:**

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.1.1       hostname

    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What's in your `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for `hosts:`?

Comment: The info is added to the question.

Comment: What nameserver do your lookups come from if you remove the `@192.168.122.1` from your `dig`?  The next step will be to `tcpdump -n port 53` while doing the above failing commands.

Comment: A nameserver was not being contacted. That was the really weird thing to me. The problem is now solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the `resolv.conf.d` version, but I believe you should put the lookup settings in `/etc/resolv/resolv.conf.d/base` instead of `/etc/resolv/resolv.conf.d/original`

Comment: That did it! And it lead me to another answer, which I'll post in addition. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer, where the `nameserver` directive goes in the `/etc/resolv/resolv.conf.d/base` file is *one* way of managing the nameserver setting in ubuntu's new `resolvconf` subsystem, but there is also another way, which I had been attempting with my config.

Nameservers can also be set in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file using the `dns-nameservers` directive.

My problem was a *typo*! I had written `dns-nameservers` as "dns-servers".

I've verified both the accepted answer and this answer to work.

Comment: Thanks for writing this, it'll be useful when we do our next upgrade here!